# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id') [Discord Slash Commands]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get a little familiar with the slash command handler, but I get an error when trying to grab the member id, this happens with just about everything I try to grab.

***Here at the top is directly my command, where I try to send a message with the content "user.id".***

**this is my command:**

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("avatar")
    .setDescription("SERVUSSS")
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName("member").setDescription("memberdings").setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
        await interaction.reply(`${user.id}`);
    }
}
```

**this is my deploy file:**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require("fs");
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const commands = [];

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

commandFiles.forEach(commandFile => {
    const command = require(`./commands/${commandFile}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
});

const restClient = new REST({version: "9"}).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

restClient.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.APPLICATION_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID),
{body: commands }).then(() => console.log("success")).catch(console.error);
```

**my index file:**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({intents: []});
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

commandFiles.forEach(commandFile => {
    const command = require(`./commands/${commandFile}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
});

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("ready!!");
});


client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)

    if(command) {
        try {
            await command.execute(interaction)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)

            if(interaction.deferred || interaction.replied) {
                interaction.editReply("error")
            } else {
                interaction.reply("error")
            }
        }
    }
})


client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

I actually stick to it pretty much all the time
https://discordjs.guide/ just do not understand what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

Since option name is member then it's going to be

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser('member');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your command file, the name for the option is given as member, but when you are using `interaction.options.getUser()`, you are passing the name as 'target'. So all you have to do is change the line where you are declaring the user to: `const user = interaction.options.getUser('member')`